# How To Get Email from Twitter in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I used the following code to get email id from twitter but I am unable to fetch email id can any one help me out.

```
if(session)
{
    TWTRAPIClient *client = [TWTRAPIClient clientWithCurrentUser];
    NSURLRequest *request = [client URLRequestWithMethod:@"GET"
                                                         URL:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json"
                                                  parameters:@{@"include_email": @"true", @"skip_status": @"true"}
                                                       error:nil];

    [client sendTwitterRequest:request completion:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
        NSLog(@"Responce :%@",response);

    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just one step away from your solution. Try this code.

```
 TWTRAPIClient *client = [TWTRAPIClient clientWithCurrentUser];
        NSURLRequest *request = [client URLRequestWithMethod:@"GET"
                                                         URL:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json"
                                                  parameters:@{@"include_email": @"true", @"skip_status": @"true"}
                                                       error:nil];

        [client sendTwitterRequest:request completion:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
            NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];
            NSLog(@"%@",dictionary);
            NSURL *pictureURL = [NSURL URLWithString:dictionary[@"profile_image_url_https"]];
            NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:pictureURL];
            NSDictionary *userDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:dictionary[@"screen_name"],@"name",dictionary[@"name"],@"email",imageData,@"image", nil];
        }];
```

Comment: here i cant retrive email id , In the above Dictionary  you have given name as value for email :    
NSDictionary *userDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:dictionary[@"screen_name"],@"name",**dictionary[@"name"],@"email"**,imageData,@"image", nil];